# Java can't find right ODBC-Datasource

Tags: java, odbc

I created a BIRT report and deployed it to tomcat. It runs fine on localhost, but not on the server. The app doesn't find the right ODBC datasource. But the datasource is configured exactly the same on both systems (Vista / Small Business Server).

The ODBC datasources are configured on the local systems. I am using this url:

```
jdbc:odbc:odbcDatasource
```

The concrete RDBMS is on another system. The ODBC datasorce is configured for remote acces to the it.

```
Why can't the programm find the datasource?
How do write the url to connect to an remote ODBC datasource? 


"jdbc:odbc://host/datasource" ?
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver as the JDBC Driver

Comment: "jdbc:odbc:odbcDatasource" is the correct format of the URL. Have you tested that the ODBC driver itself works?
Are you trying to access a REMOTE ODBC datasource? YOu can't do that.  The ODBC datasource needs to be configured on the same machine that you are running the code.  If you want to access a remote DB, you should be able to get a normal JDBC driver for it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I fixed it now. This it not a Java issue. It is a Windows 32 / 64 ODBC issue. Have a look here, if you have similar problems: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976/en-us